# How can I add an exitable slideshow to my website when a user clicks a thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, image, slideshow

I am building a travel website, and I would like to make a responsive grid/row of thumbnails that can be clicked, causing a slideshow to cover the screen with a full image of the thumbnail that they clicked.  The user can click arrows on the side of the image to toggle between other images in the same set, or hit an 'x' in the corner to exit the slideshow and return to the page at the exact same spot that they were at.

Simply put, I want to copy the behavior when you click an image in a Bing or Google image search, or click on a photo in a Facebook photo album.

I figured that this would be a common and easy-to-do task, but my research so far has only yielded full-page bootstrap carousels that people put on their home page.  That honestly sounds like a terrible idea to me, since that would fill up lots of space and push more important content down the page.

Is there an easy way or existing library for doing this?

For what it's worth, my website is currently built in Angular 4 and uses bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is called a 'Lightbox'.  My search was successful when I started to think of the slideshow as a pop-up.

There are a few different popular existing implementations:

[angular2-lightbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-lightbox)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp)

[FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

[FeatherLight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/)

[bootstrap-lightbox](https://jbutz.github.io/bootstrap-lightbox/)

[ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

[Magnific](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

[Chocolat](http://chocolat.insipi.de/)